# Runnable snippets: Extension is missing

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I use [htmx](//htmx.org) which uses this URL for their JavaScript:

`https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.1.0`

This gets rejected, if I try to add it to a runnable stack snippet.

What should I do now?

[image]

It gets rejected:

[image]

Comment: That link redirects me to `https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.1.0/dist/htmx.min.js` - does that work for you?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, this works. But wouldn't be nice, if it would work out of the box?

Comment: How will it know what type of file it is then? It needs to be able to differentiate them because css uses <link> and js uses <script>.

Comment: @SuperStormer is there no way to auto-detect CSS/JS?

Answer (score 3):

The dialogue you describe is just a shortcut telling the system to add a `<script>` (or `<link>`, in the case of css) tag to your snippet- nothing ever stops you from adding one manually that uses a shortened unpkg.com link.

Just make sure you know whether you're adding a css or js file, as pointed out by [@SuperStormer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7941251/superstormer).

Eg:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'Hello world!',
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ text }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How could the first-time-user-experience get improved, to make this more like "don't make me think"?